# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Arraylist

Tags: java, android-studio, netbeans

I am working with array list of objects  in Netbeans and save it in files and i would to read it in an application in android studio but log error show this java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

`Invalid index 0, size is 0`.

the package name is the same in both.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: please show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question and post a piece of your code that occur error.